# Convert DefaultListModel to List in Java

Tags: java, list, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I'm making a Swing application that includes a JList and all the objects in the list are stored in a DefaultListModel. At the same time I need to pass the list to a method that receives as input a List. How can i convert a DefaultListModel to a List ?

This is the error i got:

```
The method computeSpending(List<Subscription>) in the type SubscriptionSpending is not applicable for the arguments (DefaultListModel<Subscription>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i convert a DefaultListModel to a List ?

**Arrays.asList(defaultListModel.toArray());**

---

Description:

`DefaultListModel` is not a subclass of `List`. So it is not directly possible to pass that as a `List` argument. Instead you can change the parameter type to `ListModel<E>`. Such as:

```
computeSpending(ListModel<Subscription>)
```

Also,
If you must need to pass the `DefaultListModel<Subscription>` into a `List`, you can use:

```
List<Subscription> asList = Arrays.asList(defaultListModel.toArray());
```

Comment: With the second method i got: The method computeSpending(List<Subscription>) in the type SubscriptionSpending is not applicable for the arguments (List<Object>)

Comment: @pz7, You can't "convert" it to a List<Subscription>. The best you can do is convert it to a List<Object>. However the best solution is to forget about using a List and pass the DefaultListModel to your computeSpending(...) method. The DefaultListModel has a `get(...)` method just like the List.get(..), so there is no logic change in your method. If you really want a List<Subscription> then you need to *copy* the data from the model to the list. But this is not a good solution because now you have a reference to the data in two places.

Comment: My problem is that the method computeSpending(...) needs to work also with List<Subscription> as input.

Comment: FYI, since Java 9, a modern alternative would be [`List.of( defaultListModel.toArray() )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E...)). This returns an [unmodifiable `List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable), an instance of an unspecified concrete class.